# Errors with the moderncv template used with w32tex

Tags: errors, moderncv

I want to prepare my resume using the moderncv package. I am using w32tex (installed on this September), which includes the moderncv package. I downloaded the template from CTAN https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples and complied the file using lualatex. There was no problem at this point.

However, when I changed style from *casual* to *classic*, the following error message was displayed:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadi',
               but the package provides `moderncvheadi'.

Package: moderncvheadi 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 1 \quotewidth=\skip262\makecvheadnamewidth=\skip263
) (c:/w32tex/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvbodyi.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyi',
               but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.

Package: moderncvbodyi 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1 \hintscolumnwidth=\skip264\separatorcolumnwidth=\skip265\maincolumnwidth=\skip266\doubleitemcolumnwidth=\skip267\listitemsymbolwidth=\skip268LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+mvs on input line 46.
(c:/w32tex/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/umvs.fd)

! Font \U/mvs/m/n/10.95=umvs at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.

<to be read again> 
relax 

l.46 ...width{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
?
```

Even if I ignore this error and press Enter, another error showed up:

```
 ! Font \U/mvs/m/n/10=umvs at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
 <to be read again> 
 relax 

 l.57 \makecvtitle
 ?
```

I really cannot fix this problem. Is some package lacking? Since I just changed style of the template, I don't think there is any problem in the source file.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't know what w32tex is, but it seems as if you are missing some files. For me, it works just fine. If feasable for you, I would recommend to go to https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv and just download the files you need in to your working directory. At least for a first test.

Comment: umvs is the marvosym font, you need to install it.

Comment: I have installed the marvosym package just now and used the template file of moderncv from CTAN. Nevertheless, the problem occurs.

Comment: The same error or another?

Comment: @Bob: Please check that your installation of marvosym is OK or not.
How to install marvosym:
Expand marvosym.zip. There are 4 subdirectories, doc, fonts, source, and tex.
Copy three of them, doc, fonts, and tex, into texmf-local.
Then execute `mktexlsr`, and `updmap --add marvosym.map`.
W32TeX is very incomplete about many packages and fonts, sorry.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: shouldn't this be `updmap ----enable Map=marvosym.map` (or `updmap-sys`)? Or has w32tex a different updmap?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: updmap in w32tex is very simple and different
from that in TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late action.
I have added marvosym font today (2016/03/06 JST) in W32TeX.
It will become available after a few days.